# return structure vs pass Reference variables

Tags: c++, struct

Which one is better if I have to return a string as well as an array from a function.

1. Create a structure containing string and array, populate that and return the instance of that structure.

Consider I have to send string "status" and an array "ids".

```
    struct ReturnValues {
      string status;
      int ids[10];
    };
```

use it as:

```
ReturnValues returnValues;
returnValues = func();
```

Consider that func() returns the object of ReturnValues

2. Pass one of them as referenced variable and return the other.

As:

```
int ids[10];
string status = func(ids);
```

Consider that func takes ids as referenced variable

```
string func(int& ids) {
  //Some code
  return status;
}
```

3. Pass both as referenced variables returning void.

As:

```
int ids[10];
string status;
func(ids, status);
```

Consider that func takes ids and status as referenced variables

```
void func(int& ids, string& status) {
  //some code;
}
```

Comment: It depends on your compiler optimization settings.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly from a performance standpoint, it would give the compiler the most leverage to optimize if you do :

```
struct ReturnValues {
  string status;
  int ids[10];
};
```

and

```
ReturnValues returnValues = func();
```

Doing

```
ReturnValues returnValues;
returnValues = func();
```

will decrease performance since return-value optimization cannot take place : http://goo.gl/5Cfmw2

Comment: Right, and the second version should also be avoided for other reasons: You cannot make returnValues const, somebody might try to access the uninitialized variable and finally it is more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for the 1st version. Functions that modify their arguments tend to make the code more difficult to understand and test.

If you are worried about performance: Practically all compilers will use return value optimization here. So this should not be an issue, maybe except in some exotic cases.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would either group them together either into a predefined `struct` as you did or use `std::pair` or `tuple` if you don't want to define one explicitly. My feeling is that things that belong together belong together (if you'll forgive the tautology). Either way I would consider using `std::array` if the array length is fixed or `std::vector` (or some collection type) if not. Am not a fan of level C type arrays such as`type A[10]` I would probably just return them as a return value simply because it shows the intent "Get me one of these things with ints and strings in it" and let the compiler sort it out